# "cd" and "cd home" bring me to different directories?

Tags: linux, terminal

I've read that typing "cd" should bring you to the home directory, but it brings me within my username directory, . that doesn't bother me, but i thought that writing "cd" was a shortcut for "cd home", so how come it brings me to two different places?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and write what you think `cd` should do or what you think your home directory should be instead of something like `/home/username`. The command `cd home` will search for a subdirectory named `home` in the current directory (and maybe other locations specified in `CDPATH`) and switch to the first directory found this way. `cd home` is different from `cd /home` or `cd $HOME` (= `cd` without argument).

Answer (score 1):

From the `cd` man page

> 1. If no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is empty or undefined, the default behavior is implementation-defined and no further steps shall be taken.
> 2. If  no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is set to a non-empty value, the cd utility shall behave as if the directory named in the HOME environment variable was specified as the directory operand.

Almost everyone has their `$HOME` variable set. Almost all the time it will be your user home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX/Linux world a `username` directory is usually the `home` directory.

You can see/change path to `home` directory via `$HOME` env variable.